# Issue with last column width in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, highcharts

i am rendering the Highcharts after the loading the table data dynamically using Datatable.

I am facing the problem with the with of the bar in chart.
please check the code below how it looks like.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highcharts/4.1.5/modules/broken-axis.js">
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="advertiser_chart"></div>
        <table id="datatable">
            <thead>
                <tr role="row">
                    <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Month</th>
                    <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Order</th>
                    <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Revenue</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr role="row" class="odd">
                    <td>2016</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>11</td>
                </tr>
                <tr role="row" class="even">
                    <td>2015</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr role="row" class="odd">
                    <td>2014</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr role="row" class="even">
                    <td>2013</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr role="row" class="odd">
                    <td>2012</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#advertiser_chart').highcharts({
        data: {
            table: 'datatable'
        },
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        yAxis: {
            allowDecimals: false,
            title: {
                text: ''
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
            allowDecimals: false,
            title: {
                text: ''
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                //return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' + this.point.y + ' ' + this.point.name.toLowerCase();
                return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' + this.y;    
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                //pointWidth: 40,// Remove padding between olumns
            }
        }
    });
    </script>
</html>
```

Any solution i can get ?

Here is the fiddle as well

https://fiddle.jshell.net/ra527ee8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are rendering the table data Dynamically then try to load the data with ascending order in case it is in descending.

your table should look like below, and Replace table body :

```
<tbody>
                <tr role="row" class="odd">
                    <td>2012</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr role="row" class="even">
                    <td>2013</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr role="row" class="odd">
                    <td>2014</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr role="row" class="even">
                    <td>2015</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr role="row" class="odd">
                    <td>2016</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>11</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
```